# AJAX call to PHP not returning value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have 3 files linked together `index.php` `functions.js` and `compute.php`

`index.php` has a div that calls a function in `functions.js`: `compute()` that sends an AJAX request to do something in `compute.php`

`index.php`:

```
<form id = "input_form">
    <textarea name = "row" id = "inputform" placeholder="Input row here"></textarea> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "Enter" onclick="compute(inputform.value);">
</form>
<div id = "output_container">
    <p id = "output"></p>
</div>
```

When the button is pressed, `compute()` is called passing in whatever was in the `textarea` as data.

```
function compute(row){
    var xhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
            output.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","compute.php?row="+row,true);
    xhttp.send(null);
}
```

This passes the value into a php script which simply is suppose to output what was in the textarea into `#output`

```
<?php

$str = $_GET['row'];
echo $str;

?>
```

When I test my program by clicking the button, nothing happens indicating something went wrong. I tried to pinpoint the problem by adding a `window.alert('something');` after the check `if(xhttp.readyState == 4)` but a popup box never appears, making it seem like the issue is between functions and compute.

I tested out `phpinfo();` and it looks like php is working properly on my server as well

Comment: shouln't it be `$_GET` instead of `@_GET`??

Comment: @_GET is not a variable

Comment: @Jeff good catch! Unfortunately it doesn't work with `$_GET` either.

Comment: can you clarify what 'doesn't work' means exactly? in networktab: do you see the request going out? do you see data coming back?

Comment: `xhttp.open` and `xhttp.send` have to be outside the `onreadystatechange` callback. Why did you put them inside? You might want to have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started or  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest .

Comment: @FelixKling good catch! just the sentence can be misunderstood: 'have to be' instead of 'have been'

Comment: @SemicolonExpected also change `xhttp.responseXML` to `xhttp.responseText`

Comment: @Jeff I've actually tried both `.responseXML` and `.responseText` I see the request go out in the network tab, but no data coming back.

Comment: hm... have you tried calling `compute.php?row=dummytext` directly? Do you see responseheaders? (changing to 400 or maybe smth else)

Comment: Ah! Are you triying to send and receive html-code? Then you would have to url-encode that first! (and method GET would not be a good choice for that then)

Comment: @Jeff I'm trying to send plaintext, would I have to encode that as well? It doesn't respond even when I hardcode `?row=sometext`

Comment: then you php isn't working! you got a proper server set up? (wamp, easyphp, apache, ....)

Comment: @Jeff I have a server with LAMP installed.

Comment: @Jeff I checked to make sure and apache2 is working and I'm running PHP 5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Form is getting submitted without making ajax call, because your code contains **type='submit'**

**Solution:** Change type to button:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Enter" onclick="compute(inputform.value);">
```

Also update code to fetch the output properly:

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
```